# How to update shell programs

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

How do I update shell programs like `crontab` for example?
On my Mac I've got version from 29th of December 1993, but on a server linux machine that I am using version of crontab is much better in terms of usability since it's from 19th of April 2010.

I am running MacOS Mojave and my bash version is :
`GNU bash, version 5.0.2(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0)`

crontab on my Mac:
[image: Mac]
crontab on my Linux:
[image: Linux]

Comment: How did you update your `bash`?

Comment: With homebrew (https://brew.sh). Once you install it run `brew install bash`. And once it's done you need to add your current shell's directory (check the directory of it by running `which bash`) to `/etc/shells`. And then finally change your shell by running change shell command : `chsh -s "shell's directory you've added to /etc/shells"`

Comment: It was kind of a rhetoric question :-)

Comment: `crontab` is deprecated, by the way.  You should be using `launchd` instead  See `man crontab`

Comment: A quick check of the source code for `vixie crontab`, available at Apple OpenSource, shows that `crontab.c` was modified in September of 2006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the executable?

```
command -v cron
```

The result shows `/usr/sbin/cron`. [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP) protects the contents of `/usr`; thus we cannot affect a change anyway as long as SIP is enabled. You installed BASH via Homebrew, I take it. Searching Homebrew for cron-related formulae or casks reveals no candidates (`brew search cron`), perhaps for reasons given by @nohillside. Perhaps `cron` was a bad example and a better example might be `vim`. As you have discovered, one can utilize a package manager like Homebrew or Macports to install more recent software. For each installed package, Homebrew, at least, installs a symbolic link to wherever the executable was installed (`/usr/local/Cellar/[...]`); thus, we could utilize a shell alias or modify the `PATH` environment variable to utilize better versions of common software. I use the shell alias approach.

For example, my shell is `zsh`, and I have installed MacVim. If the symbolic link for MacVim's version of `vim` exists (`-h`), then define a new alias. Now, every time I execute `vim`, I am not executing the `vim` located in `/usr/bin`; rather, I am executing the `vim` located in `/usr/local/bin`. The below test and definition works the same for bash.

```
[ -h '/usr/local/bin/vim'  ] && alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'
[ -h '/usr/local/bin/view' ] && alias view='/usr/local/bin/view'
```

And then use the package manager to update the software periodically.

```
if brew update 2>/dev/null; then
    brew upgrade
    brew cleanup
    rm -rf "$(brew --cache)"
fi
```

Comment: Might be easier to put `/usr/local/bin` in front of `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` (and in `/etc/paths`), otherwise you need to define aliases for each command you install. Also, aliases don't work in scripts (well, at least not in bash, don't know about zsh).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the note @nohillside. Yes, I alluded to the `PATH` approach. Myself, I don't use aliases in scripts - just the interactive shell.

Comment: @nohillside Oh! And we only need an alias if the same command already exists in the `PATH` before `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 3):

The content of `/usr/bin` and friends is updated with each release of macOS, but usually the versions shipped by Apple are significantly older than what's available on Linux. There are various reasons for this, in a lot of cases it's related to changes in the GPL. In case of `crontab` it may also play a role that the use of `cron` is deprecated, `launchd` should be used instead.

If you want to update Unix binaries yourself

- Use Homebrew (https://brew.sh)
- Compile from source yourself and install in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: When I tried `brew install cron` and `brew install crontab` it only said that no available formulas with those names.

Comment: But like you've said I think I will start to use `launchd` instead, thanks!

Comment: @Victor Yeah, looks like there is no formula for `cron`. You still can compile yourself, but I'm not sure it's worth the hassle.